# Admob Native advanced small add size

Tags: android-studio, admob

Im trying to add Native advanced ads to my app. I need  banner size native ads, can this type of ads be implemented without MediaView e.g com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.MediaView,  but just imageView advertiser logo  ?

In temeplate there is two types of ads small and medium: 
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/templates
(i cant use temeplates because is not supported by androidX yet)

Here google saying that that primary large image is recommended
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6240809?hl=en&ref_topic=7384666

But here that image is required
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6329638

Comment: Did you find any solution for banner size native advanced template ?